# Cumulative Sum Distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, cumulative-sum

I have a view `refv_ActiveOpen` which has `SuburbName, Weeks, ServiceCount`and from it i want to create a second view which will show the `ServiceCount` accumulating per week. The view must have distinct Weeks and Suburbname. For example:

```
  SuburbName |Weeks|ServiceCount|Accumulative
   Pretoria  |1    |100         |100
   Pretoria  |2    |30          |130
 Johannesburg|1    |30          |30
 Johannesburg|2    |20          |50
```

Above are the results I want to display. For each and every suburb there should be a column that show distinct suburbs and how the running total goes per week per suburb. I managed to get an overall running total but thats not what I am looking for. Please assist

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Specify appropriate DBMS?

Comment: You should include the code you have used for the overall running total.

Comment: I am using sql server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANSI-SQL, should work with any RDBMS:

```
SELECT t1.SuburbName, t1.Weeks, t1.ServiceCount, sum(t2.ServiceCount) as Accumulative
FROM refv_ActiveOpen t1
INNER JOIN refv_ActiveOpen t2
  ON t1.SuburbName = t2.SuburbName -- Same suburb
  AND t1.Weeks >= t2.Weeks -- All the weeks up to the week from t1.
GROUP BY t1.SuburbName, t1.Weeks, t1.ServiceCount
```

This uses a self-join to produce for each row of your table (aliased `t1`) the set of matching rows for the same suburb with week number *the same or lower*. The latter rows are then sum'ed to get the accumulated service number for the prior weeks.

Comment: This statement groups the values I want to accumulate in the t2.Service_Count column. How can I incorporate it with your statement to get the desired results? SP_Name refers to the suburb name`SELECT Distinct t2.Weeks, t2.SP_NAME, SUM(t2.Service_Count) as service_count 
From refv_ActiveOpen1 t2 
group by t2.Weeks, t2.SP_NAME 
order by Weeks asc`

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You may want to open another question specifying what exactly the desired result of this is.

Answer (score 0):

In most databases, you can use the ANSI standard cumulative sum function:

```
select t.*,
       sum(Service_Count) over (partition by SuburbName order by weeks) as accumulative
from refv_ActiveOpen t;
```

This has been supported in SQL Server since version 2012.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sum and order by windowing function

```
Select *, accumulative =  sum(service count) over(partition by suburb name, weeks order by weeks) from yourtable
```